# Storing arraylist of User's into mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I want to store arraylist of User object.It's size is about 50,000, means 50,000 users.
So will it be possible to store into mysql.? upto how much limit i can store data into mysql.?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just do it. 50000 is a tiny number for a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mysql Scalability and Limits**

Support for large databases. We use MySQL Server with databases that contain 50 million records. We also know of users who use MySQL Server with 200,000 tables and about 5,000,000,000 rows.

Support for up to 64 indexes per table (32 before MySQL 4.1.2). Each index may consist of 1 to 16 columns or parts of columns. The maximum index width is 767 bytes for InnoDB tables, or 1000 for MyISAM; before MySQL 4.1.2, the limit is 500 bytes. An index may use a prefix of a column for CHAR, VARCHAR, BLOB, or TEXT column types.

Also check these links-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/features.html

http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=672